# Is there a conventional term for a modification to an equation that makes it false?

Tags: terminology

Suppose you have an equation like $1+1=2$. Now, if in the next line I say something like "therefore $1+1+1=-3$, then is there a conventional word that is used to describe the way you change an equation such that it then becomes false, whereas it was previously true?

Comment: The word "fallacy" means roughly that: Dictionary.com gives one definition as "A failure in reasoning that renders an argument invalid."

Comment: Also this may be a better question for the [English Language & Usage site](https://english.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Sure, it's called a mistake, or an error. "The error in the above proof is..."